# boost::process throws LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, boost

I've installed Boost using vcpkg. Now I'm trying a "Hello World" with Boost:process.  Suppose I start with Boost commented out everything works fine

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <boost/process.hpp>
//#include <boost/process/windows.hpp>

//namespace bp = boost::process;
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int result = std::system("echo Hello");
}
```

Now if I uncomment Boost but don't use it i.e. I still call

```
std::system("echo Hello");
```

it compiles but throws two link errors

```
"__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (__imp_?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'native_ecat''(void)" (??__Enative_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
"__declspec(dllimport) class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (__imp_?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::system::`dynamic initializer for 'errno_ecat''(void)" (??__Eerrno_ecat@system@boost@@YAXXZ)
```

I've tried adding Additional Library Dependencies for

```
C:\vcpkg-master\installed\x86-windows\lib
C:\vcpkg-master\packages\boost_x86-windows\debug\bin
C:\vcpkg-master\packages\boost_x86-windows\debug\lib
C:\vcpkg-master\packages\boost_x86-windows\lib
C:\vcpkg-master\packages\boost_x86-windows\bin
```

but none of those resolve the error.
Does anyone know where to find the correct link librries?

If I actually call Boost with 
int result = bp::system("echo Hello");
there are 9 unresolved externals.

As far as I can see, it's an installer issue with VCPKG.

Comment: It seems more likely to be an issue with vcpkg.  There's a cryptic C:\vcpkg-master\packages\boost_x86-windows\lib\manual-link folder but that doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it manually, I added this directory to

```
$(SolutionDir)..\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib
```

To

```
Project -> Properties-> Liker -> Additional Library Directories
```

and added this line to stdafx.h

```
#pragma comment(lib, "boost_system-vc140-mt-1_65_1.lib")
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't seem to work but I think the root cause was the VC installation itself.  I uninstalled and reinstalled an earlier version with some different parameters and it's now working.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link boost_system. How you achieve that in your setup is up to you. Usually on MSVC it's automatic.

See the relevant documentation which has several useful approaches with examples: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/windows.html#link-your-program-to-a-boost-library